# Put a value in CDATA and get him out of there

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have such a problem here: service with which I integrating, has a strange format.

takes the value:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <Operation>
            <XmlStream>
                <Name>GetPolicys</Name>
                <XML><![CDATA[
                  <Arra>
                    <Ul>
                      <LastName>---</LastName>
                      <FirstName>---</FirstName>
                      <FatherName>---</FatherName>
                      <Birthday>---</Birthday>
                    </Ul>
                  </Array>]]>
                </XML>
            </XmlStream>
        </Operation>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and returns

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <OperationResponse>
            <OperationResult>
                <ResultName>GetPolicys</ResultName>
                <XML><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <Array>
                      <Ul>
                        <LastName>----</LastName>
                        <FirstName>----</FirstName>
                        <FatherName>---</FatherName>
                        <Birthday>--</Birthday>
                        <PolicyList>
                         ----
                        </PolicyList>
                      </Ul>
                    </Array>]]>
                </XML>
            </OperationResult>
        </OperationResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

create a nested message I got. As it wrapped in a CDATA? How to get it from CDATA in the preparation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XSLT](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/11/extracting-cdata-section-using-xslt.html) to pick out from CDATA..